# Solving Neumann boundary wave equation with D'Alambert's formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following IBVP:

\begin{cases}
u_{tt} = 4u_{xx},\\
u_x(0,t) = 0, \\
u(x,0) = 1, u_t(x,0) = x \\
\end{cases}

with x > 0, t > 0. I have tried using D'Alambert's formula $u$(x,t) = $\frac{1}{2}\phi$(x - ct) + $\frac{1}{2}\phi$(x + ct) + $\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}$ for x > ct, giving the solution u(x,t) = 1 + tx, and the evenly reflected version of D'alambert's Formula for $u$(x,t) $\frac{1}{2}\phi$(ct - x) + $\frac{1}{2}\phi$(x + ct) + $\frac{1}{2c}\int_{0}^{ct-x}\psi$(s)ds + $\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^{x+ct}\psi$(s)ds for x < ct giving the solution u(x,t) = 1 + $\frac{x^2}{4} + t^2$. However, the solution is apparently not supposed to be C$^2$ differentiable, but should have a jump discontinuity somewhere, which my solution doesn't seem to have. Am I making a mistake somewhere in my solution, or am I missing something?